# Fast way to create a view

Tags: android, caching, layout, view, rendering

This question has been bugging me for a while now.

The idea is that I want to use a way to draw/create a view in a fast way.
I read that XML layout has more advantages than a dynamic one.

I read also about caching. Apparently, we cannot/shouldn't cache the whole UI element. If we save its state/value and re-create it, doesn't it take the same time as creating it from scratch? Is there a significant way to draw a view in a faster way?

**What's my goal?**

Say if I have different activities in an android app; the second time I visit an activity, I want it to "render" faster to optimize the performance and usability. Is there a way, like caching for example, or any other way? Or am I stuck with re-creating each activity from scratch from XML Layout or programmatically?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts..

Comment: what actually do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

> the second time I visit an activity, I want it to "render" faster to optimize the performance and usability

Well, it will do that to an extent on its own, as your resources will already be loaded into the process.

You can also bring an existing instance of the activity to the foreground, creating a fresh one if there is no currently-running instance, via things like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. However, that's more of a way of controlling navigation, more so than specifically addressing performance.

You are also welcome to minimize your number of activities, going with more of a "fat activity" architecture, heavily leveraging fragments, where you can do a bit more caching of actual views.

If you have existing code that is exhibiting performance issues, use tools like Traceview to figure out where your time is being spent, rather than just guessing.

Comment: That's a good answer. Do you have an idea if I pass the instance of the objects and saved them in a different class and when I'm back to a specific activity I reset the content view from a layout instance saved before, is it significantly faster than re-creating it? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Chris: I have no idea what "the objects" are. Worry about performance problems that exist, and then use tools to determine where those performance problems lie. Randomly guessing as to potential problems, then randomly guessing as to potential solutions, is wasting your time.

Comment: The objects are for example a Button, TextView, LinearLayout, etc.
I know that it's a non-existing problem till now; But I was just thinking if there's a way that a view/layout can be pre-fetched somehow or loaded from cache @CommonsWare